# Jboss server not starting

Tags: jboss, jvm, jbpm

i am installatng the JBoss server and starting it as part of  jbpm installation.
when i start the server with ant start.demo syntax, i am getting the below error in log file,

```
13:13:55,082 INFO  [org.jboss.jaxr] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS014000: Started JAXR subsystem, binding JAXR connection factory into JNDI as: java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory
13:13:55,082 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:13:55,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
13:13:57,250 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
13:13:58,014 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\New folder\jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
13:13:58,014 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment dashboard-builder.war
13:13:58,046 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment jbpm-console.war
13:14:03,256 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.network.public: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.public: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface public

13:14:03,287 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "jbpm-console.war"
13:14:03,287 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "dashboard-builder.war"
13:14:35,610 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.dashboard-builder.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.lang:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:14:35,610 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.dashboard-builder.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.lang:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:14:35,626 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.dashboard-builder.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.io:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:14:35,626 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.dashboard-builder.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.io:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:14:35,626 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.dashboard-builder.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.collections:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:14:35,626 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.dashboard-builder.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.collections:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:14:35,626 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.dashboard-builder.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.codec:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:14:35,642 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.dashboard-builder.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.codec:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:14:35,642 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.dashboard-builder.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:14:35,642 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.dashboard-builder.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:14:35,907 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment dashboard-builder.war
13:14:38,372 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: dashboard-builder.war
13:14:38,434 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) WELD-000900 1.1.5 (AS71)
13:15:49,679 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,679 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry batik-all-1.7.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,695 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry commons-io-1.3.1.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,695 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry commons-logging-1.0.4.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,695 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry serializer-2.7.0.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,695 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry servlet-2.2.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,695 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xalan-2.7.0.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,710 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,710 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis-1.3.04.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,710 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,710 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xmlgraphics-commons-1.3.1.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,710 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry fop-hyph.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,710 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jai_codec.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,726 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jai_core.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,726 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jai_imageio.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,757 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jimi-1.0.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,757 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xmlunit1.0.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,757 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,757 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,773 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,773 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,773 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,773 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,773 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,773 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,788 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jbpmmigration-0.11.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,788 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry log4j-1.2.16.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jbpmmigration-0.11.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,804 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,804 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,804 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,866 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry serializer.jar in "/D:/New folder/jbpm-6.0.0.Final-installer-full/jbpm-installer/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:15:49,991 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext,org.springframework.beans.BeansException,org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerResolver' for service type 'org.apache.cxf.bus.factory'
13:15:50,007 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
13:15:50,007 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
13:15:50,194 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for org.jbpm.domain
13:15:52,815 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.jbpm-console.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.netty:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:15:52,815 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.jbpm-console.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.netty:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
13:15:52,924 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment jbpm-console.war
13:15:52,986 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named RetryTrackerSingleton in deployment unit deployment "jbpm-console.war" are as follows:

    java:global/jbpm-console/RetryTrackerSingleton!org.kie.services.remote.jms.RetryTrackerSingleton
    java:app/jbpm-console/RetryTrackerSingleton!org.kie.services.remote.jms.RetryTrackerSingleton
    java:module/RetryTrackerSingleton!org.kie.services.remote.jms.RetryTrackerSingleton
    java:global/jbpm-console/RetryTrackerSingleton
    java:app/jbpm-console/RetryTrackerSingleton
    java:module/RetryTrackerSingleton

13:15:53,901 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
13:15:53,901 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
13:15:53,911 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010402: Unable to instantiate driver class "org.h2.Driver": org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.jbpm-console_warorg_h2_Driver_1_3 is already registered
13:15:53,911 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: jbpm-console.war
13:15:53,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015954: Admin console is not enabled
13:15:53,931 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 140455ms - Started 323 of 754 services (376 services failed or missing dependencies, 53 services are passive or on-demand)
13:15:54,131 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "jbpm-console.war" was rolled back with no failure message
13:15:54,141 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "dashboard-builder.war" was rolled back with failure message JBAS014750: Operation handler failed to complete
13:15:55,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment dashboard-builder.war in 1596ms
13:15:59,537 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment jbpm-console.war in 5393ms
13:15:59,537 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.JmsXA (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.jbpm-console.jbpm-console.env."org.kie.services.remote.jms.RequestMessageBean".connectionFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.module.jbpm-console.jbpm-console.env."org.kie.services.remote.jms.RequestMessageBean".factory] 
      service jboss.ra.hornetq-ra (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".component.JMSAuditProcessor.CREATE, service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".component.TaskServiceRequesMessageBean.CREATE, service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".component.KieSessionRequesMessageBean.CREATE] 

13:15:59,537 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => "JBAS014750: Operation handler failed to complete"}}
13:15:59,552 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
```

Can any one of you help to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In order to deploy JBPM in jboss server we need run in standalone-full mode.

In jboss->standalone-->configuration standalone.xml and standalone-full.xml will be there. Normally jboss will configured with standalone.xml so we need to change as standalone-full.xml and run.

This error will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the new versions? 6.1 and 6.2.CRx ?
That kind of issue seems to be caused because the application server wasn't started with the full profile, but ant start.demo should that for you, unless you modify it in some way or provided another server installation.